# Remove print button from Form and List view Odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I need to remove Print button from Form and List view. I tried below code for Form view.

***.xml**

```
<xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="print">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

***.js**

```
instance.web.FormView.include({
    load_form: function(data) {
        this._super(data);
        console.log('this',this.sidebar);
        if (this.is_action_enabled('print')) {
          var no_print = _.reject(this.sidebar.sections, function (item) {
              return item.label === _t('Print');
              });
              this.sections = no_print;
        }
      },
    });
```

But getting this error: `this` object has no attribute `sidebar`.

**NOTE:** console log prints two times, first it prints with some data second it prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the attribute menu="False" to one of your report tags will do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

Would you like remove the print from only one view of the model or for each view of the model?

Comment: only one of the model. Ex: product.product.

Comment: You can easier remove the print with this xml code "    <delete model="ir.actions.report.xml" id="product.report_product_label" />"

This method will delete the report.